# Went over a curb

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

Earlier today i went over a curb and there’s a visible damage to the sidewalk, however my uneducated eyes can’t tell if I should change the tire or not. Advise and opinions would be much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace for safety of all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change your tire and have your rim inspected.

Comment: Ah, so the rim is a write off too? ‍♂️ 

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Please don't answer tire health questions. They are off-topic for this Stack.